# Is it possible to catch mouse events from a hidden feature layer?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, features, feature-layer

I want to avoid drawing a feature layer. I want it to be hidden and load as fast as possible. I have tried with opacity zero but i think it still draws.  Is there any way to minimize the time of being put on the map? I care only for mouse events at the position of the geometries.  I need this so as to to keep the feature layer in a map containing the same poins that has been designed with a dynamic or tiles service for better performance. So i will have my points drawn as images altogether and then add the feature layer to as t catch the mouse over event and show a popup .

Comment: opacity zero won't help; it's representation. Just add feature layer when you (user) need it.

Comment: Any lighrweight form of representation?? The fastest?

Comment: You need to add some details so others can understand what you're doing. I just suggested not to add feature layers at startup of your whatever app (seems like a web page) but add means to the user (through UI) to load it when user needs it.

Comment: I will have a tiled layer and a feature layer tha will show the same points. Tiled will draw quickly. And when the features are brought i will be able t know where my geoms are and catch mouse events